# Possible to have an ApplicationScoped bean that skins a JSF 2 application with a richfaces skin?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

In production want the user to be able to write a properties file and upload that file to our production server. Once this is in place it will contain the properties needed for a richfaces skin. This file can be named whatever.

In development I want the properties file to be read from inside `WEB-INF/myprop.properties` where all my other properties files are. This file can be named whatever.

So far I have done this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="myCustomSkin ")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCustomSkin extends SkinFactoryImpl {
    /*
     * In here I call 
     * Skin s = this.buildSkin(context, "skin"); in my constructor
     * I am also overriding the loadProperties() method so it load my properties just fine
     * For some reason I can't get my app to actually use the properties I have loaded
     */
}
```

Any ideas? Basically I want to dynamically skin my richfaces application via an ApplicationScoped ManagedBean that gets initialized on startup of my Tomcat 7 server. Ideally the name of the skin file would be dynamic user input possibly read from the database or a different properties file.

EDIT 1: I have gotten it to load the properties file and then I manually (through java code) tried to insert a context-param by using `servletContext.setInitParameter("org.richfaces.skin", this.skin);` where `this.skin` is a String variable which I get the value for like this: `this.skin = s.getName();` and if you see above `s` is just the Skin object I get back from `this.buildSkin`. This comes to a `SkinNotFound Exception` because I am assuming my skin isn't getting place in my class path or something.

EDIT 2: Using JSF 2.1.17, Richfaces 4.3.0, and Tomcat7

EDIT 3: Is there a way to tell richfaces to look in a different directory for the `myskin.skin.properties` file?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/02/changing-richfaces-skins-in-runtime/

Comment: I've seen that, but what I'm doing is a little different.

Comment: What would be the difference? You're just externalizing the values into a `properties` file. Also, it would be better to use a `@SessionScoped` or all the application would change the skin (this means, every user will have the same skin).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I want every user to have the same skin. The person/people setting the skin is our client. They will set the skin for their customers. The properties files will be in a directory on the server and the application learns the name of the skin on start up not before.

Comment: Ok, in the example there there is a start name: ruby.

Comment: The thing is the example uses Skins that are built in to Richfaces and I want to override those with the properties file.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I didn't tag you in my last post sorry.

Comment: If I understand you well, you have your own skins for RichFaces and you want to load them using the external properties file and this `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Kind of... Like I said in the question. Our customers will have CRUD functionality for new properties files that will be stored on our linux server instance and will be read from there via our application. That way our customers can give their customers a custom look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement something like this RichFaces source code is your best friend.

Here is what I have found how you can do what you want:

Add a file to a jar (or anywhere so it will appear in classpath) 
`META-INF/services/org.richfaces.application.Module`
Content of the file should be `com.example.CustomModule`

Implementation of the custom module can be like this:

```
public class CustomModule implements Module {
    public void configure(ServicesFactory factory) {
        factory.setInstance(SkinFactory.class, new CustomSkinFactoryImpl());
    }
}
```

And then implement SkinFactory according to your needs, for example (if you want to extend default behavior with your CustomSkin):

```
public class CustomSkinFactoryImpl extends SkinFactoryImpl {
    public Skin getSkin(FacesContext context) {
        return new CompositeSkinImpl(new CustomSkin(), super.getSkin(context));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is similar to what I had been trying unsuccessfully.