# How to replace the value of skin parameter on the fly in Richfaces 4.3?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, skin

We have 2 applications: client application and admin application. User in admin application can change theme of client application.
If theme contains image and skin then it is doable. Image servlet is using for reading image from DB on the fly and skin is changing dynamically. I have already implemented it.
*Task is more complicated*: admin should have the possibility to customize **ANY** of the skin's parameters.
*Environment*: JSF 2, RichFaces 4.3
We can save parameters and create new skin file, but in that case we need to redeploy the client application (which is not the best solution - already implemented for custom skin).
We can change CSS on the fly, but it is big amount of classes (for all RichFaces components).
*Question*: can we **replace the value of skin parameter** (not CSS, ECSS, XCSS) **on the fly**?

Comment: For inspiration will be used [Possible to have an ApplicationScoped bean that skins a JSF 2 application with a richfaces skin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098394/possible-to-have-an-applicationscoped-bean-that-skins-a-jsf-2-application-with-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing skin parameters on the fly is not supported.

The skinning works off of resources generated from the skin file (image and CSS files) during the build. You'd have to generate new resources every time you'd change a skin parameter.

You can create a bunch of skins in advance but if you want to allow the user to change every detail there is no easy solution.

Comment: Thanks @Makhiel. I already have implemented select skin from set of default skins or enter custom skin name. And custom skin parameters are loaded in case if skin file already exist in application resources. If custom skin file doesn't exist, then default skin is used. All those works fine. One inconvenience thing is that somebody need create skin file, add it in application and redeploy application.